# Left outer join + SUM with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a table called Purchases which belongs to a Users (that is a Purchase has a foreign key to User).

The Purchases table has a column called quantity and a state_id column, both are integers.

I want to be able to **order** the Users by their completed purchases (state_id = 10) where the SUM of their quantities is bigger than > 100. That is, all the users which have a total of completed purchases > 100, should appear first, and the rest right after.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT users.id as user_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN purchases.state_id = 5 
                THEN purchases.quantity
                ELSE 0 
           END) as quantity
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchases ON purchases.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY purchases.user_id
```

But this is just returning me one User, not all of them. What am I missing?

Comment: next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster. Or at least some data sample

Comment: Oh, good call. I will do that!

Comment: I'd group by `users.id` rather than `purchases.user_id`, as the outer join will result in the latter being `NULL` if there are no matching records in the `purchases` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can JOIN only completed purchases using JOIN condition. And you should group by `users.id` not `purchases.user_id` as soon you can have users in a table without purchases at all:

```
SELECT users.id as user_id, 
       SUM(purchases.quantity) as quantity
FROM users
LEFT JOIN purchases ON (users.id=purchases.user_id) 
                       AND (purchases.state_id = 10)
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY quantity DESC
```